# Forcible Depreciation as Rent Seeking

Tags: rent

Suppose that there are two firms making widgets.

Spacely Sprockets spends €100M per year on non-labor inputs, of which €20M is depreciation on equipment and €80M is on raw materials. They spend €50M on wages and take in €200M in sales. Then their markup on costs or profits will be 33%, e.g.

```
(sales - (wages + costs )) / (wages + costs) = 50 / 150 = 0.33
```

Now suppose that Cogswell Cogs spends €130M per year on non-labor inputs, of which €20M is depreciation on equipment and €80M is on raw materials and €30M is lobbying the legislature for stricter environmental standards. They spend €50M on wages and take in €200M in sales. Then their markup on costs or profits will be 11% by the same reasoning.

Suppose the money spent on the legislature causes a law that obsoletes the machinery at Spacely Sprockets. Then the next year depreciation costs are such that their markup on costs is reduced to 10%. Is this rent seeking? What if the same law reduces Cogswell Cogs markup to 10% also, is that still rent seeking?

Presumably, if Cogswell Cogs' parent company, Vulture Ventures also owns a division that makes "green" widget making machinery, which will be purchased by Spacely Sprockets, then that is rent seeking, correct? What if Vulture Ventures REFUSES to sell to Spacely Sprockets, thereby indirectly causing them to go out of business?

Comment: I don't see why the obsolete machinery law would have anything to do with rent-seeking - unless it was put in place due to lobbying pressure from Cogswell Cogs which already has the non-obsolete machinery.

Comment: If Vulture Ventures owns Cogswell Cogs and they directed their subsidiary to spend the lobbying dollars then does it matter if Cogswell had the new machinery installed or not? Presumably, Vulture Ventures could replace the machines at cost or for free, once the old machinery is outlawed.

Comment: Yes, they can rent-seek by forcing their competitors to buy new machines. If the law is genuinely for safety reasons and VV/CC didn't push it then it's not rent-seeking even if they may have gotten some rent.